# ‘Have some more cake.’ ‘Oh, I couldn’t, thank you.’

Tags: modal-verbs

> ‘Have some more cake.’ ‘Oh, I couldn’t, thank you.’

The reply 'Oh, I couldn't, thank you.' deserves to be analyzed because the form of modal verb 'can' changed into the past tense 'could'+not.

Why 'could' was used instead of 'can'?

I already know 'could and would' is a polite expression.

Comment: "Why was 'could' used instead of 'can'?" The speaker means "I couldn't manage to eat any more (even if I wanted to because it was delicious)." It's the conditional rather than the past tense. If someone said "I can't have any more cake", it would probably be because they were diabetic or trying to lose weight, and not allowed to eat more than a ceertain amount of sweet food.

Comment: @KateBunting Can I understand the sentence as "I tried but I couldn't", where 'couldn't was used as the past tense?

Comment: No. The reply is a polite refusal to accept another slice of cake. It certainly doesn't mean that the speaker previously tried to force down another slice but had to spit it out again!!

Comment: The refusal could embody a polite pretence that the speaker was physically prevented (by fullness) from have another slice of the wonderful cake, which they would otherwise really like to have. Or the refusal might be to avoid the appearance of greed. The other person might say 'You must! Otherwise the dog will have it', and the refuser might say 'Oh go on then'. Sometimes politeness involves a to-and-fro of this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a past tense "could". There are modal senses of *could* that refer to present or even future time:

> I could play tennis with you tomorrow, if my racket is repaired.

> I suppose I could have a glass of wine. All right, please get me a glass.

The use of "could" is more tentative and so more polite.  It has a sense "I *would* be able *if*...".

<sub>These are actually linguistic fossils, In Old English, a subjunctive would be used. But the present tense subjunctive of "can" got replaced by the past tense subjunctive in all tenses, which happened to be the same as the past tense indicative.  When you see "could", it is a fossilised use of the subjunctive.  But no native speaker thinks in those terms.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

“Oh, I couldn’t,” is a set phrase, used to politely decline an offer, without giving a reason.  I’ve always interpreted this to mean, “Oh, I couldn’t *accept any more from you after you’ve been so generous already.*”

“Oh, I can’t,” does not have the same connotation.  It’s commonly used when there *is* a compelling reason not to accept.  It’s still polite, but not as extremely polite.

For example, if I offered someone a glass of wine, “Oh, I can’t,” would be more appropriate than “Oh, I couldn’t,” if the reason is something like, “It’s against my religion,” “I need to drive home after the party,” “I’m pregnant,” etc.  You could say here as well, “Oh, I can’t, but thank you.”  But you’re just as likely to hear, “Oh, I can’t.  Sorry.”  And “Oh, I couldn’t,” is only used to refuse a favor, but “Oh, I can’t,” is also used to turn town a request.